# How do I stop fadeIn() jump to top when on click?

Tags: jquery

Here an example of my code.

```
$("#slideshow img").on("click", function (e) {
    $(".fullimage").hide();
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (next.length > 0) {
        next.fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        $("#slideshow img:first-child").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When the image `fadeIn()` my page jump to top, if I change `fadeIn()` to `show()` it working fine. Let me know what it cause.

Comment: What is the HTML code of the page?

Comment: Presumably something breaks in the `fadeIn` scenario, so that `e.preventDefault()` never occurs, and the default action might here be to follow a link, to `#` say, which would give the appearance of jumping to the top of the page. There could be other explanations, such as the element being faded being in itself a major cause for the page having scroll in the first place, and by absolutely positioning it during fade, the page loses scroll height. This issue is difficult to address without an example context where the error can be reproduced. There's nothing inherently jumptotop'y about fadeIn

Comment: I think the same. Just replace `#` to `javascript:;` or `javascript:void(0)`

Comment: @DavidHedlund great! Wrapper just loses the scroll height and working fine now. Move your comment to answer so I can vote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably something of the following is going on

- A: Something breaks in the `fadeIn` scenario, so that `e.preventDefault()` never occurs, and the default action might here be to follow a link, to `#` say, which would give the appearance of jumping to the top of the page.
- B: The element being faded being in itself a major cause for the page having scroll in the first place, and by absolutely positioning it during fade, the page loses scroll height.

*Originally posted as comment but migrated to an answer upon request from OP*